# R, use binomial distribution with more than two possibilities

Tags: r, probability, binomial-cdf

I know this is probably elementary, but I seem to have a mental block. Let's say you want to calculate the probability of tossing a 4, 5, or 6 on a roll of one die. In R, it's easy enough:

```
sum(1/6, 1/6, 1/6)
```

This gives 1/2 which is the correct answer. However, I have in the back of my mind (where it possibly should remain) that I should be able to use the binomial distribution for this. I've tried various combinations of arguments for pbinom and dbinom, but I can't get the right answer.

With coin tosses, it works fine. Is it entirely inappropriate for situations where there are more than two possible outcomes? (I'm a programmer, not a statistician, so I'm expecting to get killed by the stat guys here.)

Question: How can I use pbinom() or dbinom() to calculate the probability of throwing a 4, 5, or 6 with one roll of a die? I'm familiar with the prob and dice packages, but I really want to use one of the built-in distributions.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a better question for the statistics site [stats.se]. The `*binom` functions don't know anything about the rules of dice tossing. You need to translate the real world events you are trying to predict into probabilities. There's nothing that `pbinom` adds to the mix. You know that there are 6 possible outcomes, three of which are a "success", so your probability of success is 3/6=1/2. The only function that helps is division.

Comment: check out `rmultinom` and `dmultinom`. I think this question suits this site fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Alex mentioned above, dice-throwing can be represented in terms of multinomial probabilities.  The probability of rolling a 4, for example, is

```
dmultinom(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), size = 1, prob = rep(1/6, 6)) 
# [1] 0.1666667
```

and the probability of rolling a 4, 5, or 6 is

```
X <- cbind(matrix(rep(0, 9), nc = 3), diag(1, 3))
X
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
sum(apply(X, MAR = 1, dmultinom, size = 1, prob = rep(1/6, 6)))
# [1] 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not quite obvious, this can be done with pmultinom, implemented either in [my pmultinom package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmultinom/index.html) or [this other pmultinom package on Github](https://github.com/fennerm/pmultinom).

You conceptualize it as the event that it is *not* a 1, 2 or 3. Then, you write this probability as

P(X_1 ≤ 0, X_2 ≤ 0, X_3 ≤ 0, X_4 ≤ ∞, X_5 ≤ ∞, X_6 ≤ ∞)

where X_i is the number of occurrences of side i. All the X's together have a multinomial distribution, with a size parameter of 1, and all probabilities equal to 1/6. This probability above can be calculated (using my package) as

```
pmultinom(upper=c(0, 0, 0, Inf, Inf, Inf), size=1,
          probs=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6), method="exact")
# [1] 0.5
```

Though it's a bit of an awkward reformulation, I like it because I prefer to use a "p" function rather than take a sum of "d" functions.